# LDAP query to see if a user is a member of particular groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Say I have a user (User1) and a list of groups in ranked order (Group1, Group2, Group3...).  I’m trying to figure out the most efficient way of determining the first group in the (ordered) list that a particular user is a member of, using LDAP queries.  These queries will use the “LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN” rule, so that the server knows to look in subgroups for a match as well.  That doesn’t really change much other than potentially make these queries much slower to process, which makes performance all the more important.

One option is to obtain a list of all the groups the user is a member of, then walk the list looking for the first match.  That works fine, but I’m worried that the LDAP server is going to spend all this time generating a huge list of groups when we really may only happen to need the first item in the list.

Another option is to make a series of LDAP queries, checking to see if the user is a member of each group in our list one at a time.  That doesn’t seem terribly efficient, since there could be as many queries as there are groups in the list.

What I’d like to do is make a single query where I supply the LDAP server with the list of groups, and it returns me the first group that the user is a member of, or at least it tells me which of the listed groups the user is a member of.  I have no idea if that’s actually possible.  I can certainly OR together a set of terms to see if a user is a member of *any* of the groups I have listed, but I don’t know if it’s possible to construct a query so that it tells me *which* of the terms generated a match.

Any ideas?  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the solution have to directly come from an LDAP query, could you simply cache all of the users in each group on your list (maybe refreshing that cache every ~10minutes) and then quickly search the cache when you need to check a user.

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  All things being equal, it would be great to implement this in a way where the data can never be stale, but certainly a cache that's refreshed every few minutes is pretty close to realtime.  One potentially issue would be dealing with large groups, like Domain Users.  That's a pretty large amount of data if we're saving the full list of all the members of that group.

Comment: So now you see some of the issues with nested groups and groups in general. I guess you could query the memberOf of value on the user and if you did not get a hit, then do the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN query.